# Is managing resources in destructor for monostate classes/static members a bad idea in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdthread, monostate

I'm trying to implement monostate class which manages some std::thread. Thread is running until flag become equals to false. After flag changes to false - thread stops. But looks like I have to call stoping method explicitly. Calling it in destructor brings me runtime errors (Tested on GCC 4.8 for ARM, GCC 4.9 for x86_64 and MSVC 2017).
Am I right that such behavior is due to

> "Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the
>   class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or
>   regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the
>   program."

so destructor call is omited?

Code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>


void runThread(const std::atomic<bool> &_isRunning) {

    while (_isRunning) {

        std::cout << "Me running.." << std::endl;

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(30));

    }

}

class test {

    static std::thread          thread;
    static std::atomic<bool>    isRunning;


public:

    test();
    ~test();

    static void go();
    static void stop();


};

std::thread         test::thread;
std::atomic<bool>   test::isRunning{ false };


test::test() {}

void test::go() {

    isRunning = true;
    thread = std::thread(runThread, std::ref(isRunning));

}

void test::stop() {

    isRunning = false;

    if (thread.joinable()) {

        thread.join();

    }

}

test::~test() {

    stop();

}


int main() {

    test::go();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));

    std::cout << "Done here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";

    // Will not crash anymore if uncomment
    //test::stop();

    return 0;

}
```

Using std::async with std::feature gives same result but without error. Thread just keeps running.

P.S.

---

Making the class non-monostate solves runtime errors but leaves me with this question. Is managing resources a bad practice for monostate classes/static members?

Comment: If you never instantiate a class, it's destructor will never be called.

Comment: What you're trying doesn't work, so what are you asking?

Comment: @NeilButterworth it's a monostate - it doesn't need to be instantiated itself - all members are static. And thouse members are instantiated. Check source please

Comment: @IGR94 And if it never gets instantiated the destructor will never be called.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm asking why it doesn't actually work. Trying to dig as deep as possible

Comment: I know what a monostate is - one of its features is that its destructor will never be called,  and calling the destructor seems to be what your code depends on.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I thought constructor is implicitly called on `test::go()`, so somewhere should be destructor

Comment: @IGR94  Well, I'm afraid you were misinformed. No constructor call and no destructor call.

Comment: Easy demo - add to test ctor a cout.  Note the ctor of test does not report, and thus not called.   Now invoke the ctor in main, just before "test::go()" ... ctor now does report, and dtor reports, and it works.

Comment: @NeilButterworth just checked it - you are right. Sorry, my bad. Looks like I have to reread standard. Well, now everythig clear. Add an answer please so I can mark it

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN yeah, just got it. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 ~test();
```

should be called before destroying any "test" object. You do not create "test" objects in your code, so you are right,

> Static members of a class are not associated with the objects of the
>   class: they are independent objects with static storage duration or
>   regular functions defined in namespace scope, only once in the
>   program.

Comment: But isn't constructor implicitly called when I do
`test::go()` ?

Comment: @IGR94 No, it isn't.

Comment: Well, I guess your answer was first so I accept it as a solution

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of a static object is called *before* `main` is executed, and the destructor is called *after* `main` is completed (from within `atexit`, typically).

Put a breakpoint in the destructor, it's easy to see.